# Upper bound trace of inverse of covariance matrix

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, covariance-matrix, eigenvalues, matrix-inverse

Let C be the covariance matrix from any normal distribution. If the trace of C is upper-bounded by a constant k (i.e., tr(C)<=k), can I find an upper bound for the trace of the inverse of C (i.e., tr(C^{-1})) in terms of the reciprocal of k (i.e., 1/k)?
Does anyone know any way of solving this problem?
Many thanks in advance!
Bye

Comment: *Every* covariance matrix is the covariance matrix of some Normal distribution.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to ask for a *lower* bound?  After all, even in one dimension when $\operatorname{tr}(C)\le k$ all you can say is that $1/k \le \operatorname{tr}(C^{-1}) \le \infty.$

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

For any $0< \varepsilon < 1$  consider the covariance matrix and its inverse 
$$ C = \left( \begin{matrix} 1- \varepsilon & 0 \\ 0 & \varepsilon \end{matrix}\right) \quad \quad C^{-1} = \left( \begin{matrix} (1- \varepsilon)^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & \varepsilon^{-1} \end{matrix}\right) $$
You get $\operatorname{tr}(C) = 1$  and $\operatorname{tr}(C^{-1}) = \frac{1}{(1-\varepsilon)} + \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$. This cannot be bounded above.